# Log each chuck of response from Http Request

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xmlhttprequest

im trying to build a desktop ui app that listen for change of data in my db.

im trying to log / store each chunk of response from my server, everytime my data is changed
im using MongoDB , atlas. and express.js in my serverside.

i got the response from the server everytime i hit the endpoint and changed the data manually , but i didnt recevice any log , or ui updates on my C# app. im pretty stuck on this one

C#

```
private async Task MakeHttpRequestAsync()
        {
            await Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(async () =>
            {
                using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost:3002/listen", HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);

                        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                        using (var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
                        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                        {
                            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                            {
                                string chunk = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
                                // Simply Log it to console
                                Console.WriteLine(chunk);
                                // Update the UI on the UI thread
                                tb_1.Text = chunk;

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (HttpRequestException ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"HttpRequestException: {ex.Message}");
                        if (ex.InnerException != null)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"InnerException: {ex.InnerException.Message}");
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

maybe someone can help me with the function in C# to achive what im trying to do.
a simple function will do. at least the response make it to the log

Comment: Can you try your code in a console App; by removing the Dispatcher.InvokeAsync and the text box update? You might also try to change the HttpCompletionOption to ResponseContentRead; yet however, your code works just fine for me here. Perhaps there is an issue at the server.

Comment: i havent tried my code in the console app, however my goal is building a ui app that render the each of the chunk from my response, 
at first i didnt use the dispatcher , and same result for me.

i tried hitting the endpoint from plain web browser , it show me the response of the chunk as a json.

Comment: Unless MakeHttpRequestAsync is called from a background thread, the Dispatcher call is useless here. It just delegates back to the UI thread.

Comment: As Clemens said, the Dispatcher call is redundant. You are already using the async API of HttpClient. For efficiency you should only wrap the TextBox access into adelegate i.e. dispatcher call. If you use data binding to set the text value you could completely eliminate the Dispatcher call and simply update the source property. Also note that `Console.WriteLine` requires the presence of a console instance. Because you are writing a desktop application there is no such instance. Simply use `Trace.WriteLine` or `Debug.WriteLine`. This will send the output to the Visual Studio Output window.

Comment: [`Trace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.trace?view=net-7.0) even allows you to write to a file or any other output and provides many additional features to control the logging and formatting of the messages. [`Debug`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debug?view=net-7.0) instructions (e.g. `Debug.WriteLine`) are only executed and compiled when the compiler is in debug mode. In release mode those lines are ignored by the compiler. For more complex scenarios you should use a  3rd party logger like SeriLog or Log4Net.